# Adding a button in UICollectionViewCell with a click handler using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I am rewriting a screen that used a UITableView before to UICollectionView. But I am having trouble with the click handler on a button inside the cell.

```
collectionView.RegisterNibForCell (DocumentViewCell.Nib, docCellId);    
...

public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var docCell = (DocumentViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (docCellId, indexPath);                
    docCell.BtnDelete.Hidden = !EditMode;
    docCell.BtnDelete.TouchUpInside += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Logging.Debug("Crashes before if reaches here");
    };
    return docCell;
}
```

I am aware that the cell is begin reused and this most likely won't work when that happens but now it crashes immediately with just one element in the list when pressing the delete button. Everything works great until I hit the button and then I get the stacktrace below. I see no reason for that happening based on my UITableView code that is almost identical.

Have anyone done this using Nib based CollectionView cells? Any help is very appreciated!

Stacktrace:

```
 at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0009f, 0xffffffff>
 at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
 at SalesApp.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /MyApp/Main.cs:18
 at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

0   SalesApp                            0x0009a85c mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   SalesApp                            0x0000e138 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x990a78cb _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   UIKit                               0x01990258 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
5   UIKit                               0x01a51021 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
6   UIKit                               0x01a5157f -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
7   UIKit                               0x01a506e8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
8   UIKit                               0x01c541d3 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7407
9   CoreFoundation                      0x03ecbafe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
```

**Update**

This code works fine

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var docCell = (DocumentViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (DocumentViewCell.Key, indexPath);
    docCell.BtnDelete.Hidden = !EditMode;
    docCell.BtnDelete.TouchUpInside -= HandleTouchUpInside;
    docCell.BtnDelete.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
    return docCell;
}

void HandleTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Logging.Debug("No crash");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that there's no managed reference to the `docCell` instance you return from `GetCell` method. That means the GC can collect it whenever it wants.

When it's needed again it will be *resurfaced* to the managed world (using the `IntPtr` constructor). It's gonna be the same (re-used) **native** instance but a *new* **managed** instance. Your crash occurs because the event points to the old, managed, instance (that was collected).

The easy solution is to keep a cache of the created cells as along as the view exists. That will ensure the GC won't collect the (managed) cells before they are used. There's several answers showing this for `UITableView`.

Note: I thought we fixed (hided) this in recent version of Xamarin.iOS. Maybe it was just for `UITableView` !?! need to check on this...

Comment: It seems the eventhandler for the garbage collected cell is still active somewhat because if I rewrite the button event hookup to docCell.BtnDelete.TouchUpInside -= HandleTouchUpInside; and docCell.BtnDelete.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside then everything works fine. I edited my question to show that I hide and unhide this button so maybe it is related to that? Anyway you put me on the right track so I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Hmm... maybe the **crash immediately** threw me off... One *different* issue with your earlier code is that you *may* be re-assigning the event many times when re-using a cell (and that won't happen in the 2nd case). Can you file a bug report with a, self-contained, test case and we'll have a look (at least to be sure about the condition that triggers the crash).

Comment: Yes, already made a test case out of it so I will submit it to the bug tracker tomorrow and you can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `DequeueReusableCell` returns `null` as it's the first cell being drawn.

Your code should look like this instead:

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var docCell = (DocumentViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (docCellId, indexPath);
    if (docCell == null)
        docCell = new UICollectionViewCell (...);
    docCell.BtnDelete.TouchUpInside += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Logging.Debug("Crashes before if reaches here");
    };
    return docCell;
}
```

replace the ellipses `(...)` by whatever creates your cell.

Comment: Sorry but no :-) Then I would get a nullpointer. This method is added in iOS6 and always returns a valid cell. Check this link for an example with the same code as mine: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views

Comment: `UICollectionView`, like the new (iOS6) API for `UITableView`, allow you to register the `Class` (type) of cell to create. As such there's no need anymore for check for null (less code :-)

Comment: I should have said the new API **requires** (not *allow*) you to register. The old `DequeueReusableCell` for `UITableView` can still be used with the old pattern (create if null is returned) but the new overload (new selector) also **requires** registration.